# JAVA GUI code didn't run as expected

Tags: java, user-interface

I typed this code from the book

```
public class SimpleGui3C  {

JFrame frame;


public static void main (String[] args) {
   SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
   gui.go();
}

public void go() {
   frame = new JFrame("My own code");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  
   MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

   frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

   frame.setSize(420,300);
   frame.setVisible(true);
}}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

public void painComponent(Graphics g) {
    
    g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

    Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
}}
```

the result is:
[image]

Here is the **original** code of the book, I downloaded this code from the book's website

```
public class SimpleGui3C  {

JFrame frame;

public static void main (String[] args) {
   SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
   gui.go();
}

public void go() {
   frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  
   MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
   

   frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);


   frame.setSize(420,300);
   frame.setVisible(true);
}}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     
     g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

     // make random colors to fill with
     int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
     int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
     int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

     Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
     g.setColor(randomColor);
     g.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
  }}
```

the result goes like this:
[image]

I checked it again and again to make sure that they're the same, and it seems that they are the same. but why the GUIs are different?

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a typo: painComponent

Answer (score 5):

In your own code, the method name is `painComponent` when it should be `paintComponent`.

Hint: Add `@Override` to overriden methods, then the compiler will tell you about errors like this:

```
@Override
public void painComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Comment: Indeed, `@Override` makes things less painful.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) Question for more about `@Override`